# Hide a python caused window?

Tags: python, background

I searched for a way to hide a python caused window, for example a console or a ui window, so that you can't even see the open tab from this running application.So its like all actions of the python-program never have happend.

For example you do this:

```
print("Hello World")
```

and the user souldn't see anything of this:
But I found nothing, so does anybody know how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out a way to do this by using two modules:
*This works for cmd- and GUI-windows

```
import win32console   # first module
import win32gui       # secound one
  
win = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(win, 0)  # Hides the window
win32gui.ShowWindow(win, 1)  # Shows the window
```

Edit: I found a second way to hide a terminal windows that is caused py python: All you have to do is to install pyinstaller with pip(3). Then write your sript, go to the command prompt and type in:
`pyinstaller --onefile -w <sriptname>`
-w = don't shows any console window (windows-less)

Answer (score 1):

Change the file extension of your python script file to '.pyw'. So, rename `asdf.py` to `asdf.pyw`.

This will make your script to be interpreted by a different executable than normal (precisely, `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`).

Note that I do not know whether this works on other operating systems than Windows.

Comment: But this doesnt make it "invisible" as showen in my answer above, does it?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question then. What this does is: if you start the python script (e.g. by double clicking; not from the console) it will run the script but no console window will appear and there will be no icon in the taskbar that would reveal that you are running a python script. Is this not what you were asking for?

Comment: If it is so, then you have interpreted this correctly. Thanks for this second option!